# Mongodb Like one of array items

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Consider I have a collections which it's document are like this :

```
{
   "name": "some-name",
   "age": 23,
   "foods" : ["pizza", "cola", "bread", "hotdog"]

}
```

what I need to achieve is I need to find all documents which has at least one food item which is like for example "pi".
so I want one of array items to be like search query string.

Comment: Is [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8C2_7MUTVp-) what are you looking for?

Comment: Yes, exactly Thank you very much !!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: You are welcome. I've also answered the question to explain a little more and also can be useful for any other user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do your task using [`$regex`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/).

So, using this query:

```
db.collection.find({
  "foods": {
    "$regex": "pi"
  }
})
```

Mongo will find all documents where `foods` fields contains at least one item who match the `regex` "pi".

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8C2_7MUTVp-)